# This 'that' is a relative pronoun or a pronoun?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, parts-of-speech

I want to know if 'that' of 'that identified with ~' is a relative pronoun or a pronoun in the next sentence. And the exact meaning of 'identify with', too.

....The problem was that the part involved was that identified with "musical skill."...

Comment: I'd say the second instance of ***that*** in your example *must* be a "relative pronoun", in that syntactically it's substituting as an alternative reference to preceding ***the problem***. Note that you can even have two consecutive occurrences of ***that*** (one as a "conjunction", one as a "relative pronoun") in contexts like *He insulted my mother. It was that that upset me* (but that's a bit awkward, so we'd usually switch to *...that **which** upset me*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers A demonstrative pronoun I think: the relative pronoun is omitted by whiz-deletion.

Comment: @StoneyB: Ah, that's it! I *knew* there would be a more precise term - that's why I put "relative pronoun" in scare quotes. Not that it's obvious to me how familiarity with such terminology would help anyone actually *learn* English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, it's nice to have names for the three (or four) different *thats* if you're going to talk about them: "He said that that that she offered was inadequate".

Comment: @StoneyB: Dang! *Three* consecutive instances without needing to fall back on the old "use + mention" trick!

Answer (score 1):

The final clause may be understood either as a participle clause or as a relative clause reduced by "whiz-deletion": that is, it represents

> ... <s>which is/was</s> identified with ...

In either case it modifies the preceding noun phrase, represented by *that*. This *that* is a determiner "fused" with its deleted head, a repetition of *part* (in traditional grammar, it's called a "demonstrative pronoun"):

> ... that <s>part</s> ...

Restore the deletion and the fusion and you get:

> The problem was that the part involved was that part which is/was identified with "musical skill."

*Identified with* here means approximately "declared or assumed to be the same thing as".

Comment: Thank you everyone. I thought it could be like 'the part that identified with~',  and you don't have to write 'the part' again since it is there as a suject.